# Using a file as a data source for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource

Is there a way to use a file as a data source for UITableView?

So is there an efficient way to get a line by line number?
And to get the number of lines in file?

---

**EDIT:**

The app takes every second a data point and saves it in a file.

Data point = time stamp + sensor data.

I need to show the data to the user in a UITableView and send the file to my serve every X amount of time.

Im saving the data in csv format.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited my answer with some more information, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reading files in Swift:

```
var lines = Array<String>

override func viewDidLoad() {
    do {
        let data = try NSString(contentsOfFile: "yourFile.csv", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        self.lines = data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
    } catch {
        //Handle Error
    }
}
```

Then, use each line in `lines` array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` tableView method.

Comment: This is not what i need, please see edit for more information

Comment: Is there an efficient way to get  a specific line? instead of getting  the full file at once. my file can have 10,000 + lines